# Randomizing the source port for new connections

Tags: linux, iptables

Generally whenever source port is selected by a network application, it is selected in a sequential manner among the free ports like 32000, 32001 and so on. I want to randomize the source port selection. I tried this using iptables as follows but this didn't help.

```
 Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 462 packets, 31025 bytes)
 743 44580 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           masq ports: 32768-61000 random
```

Can someone help me in solving this?

Comment: I'm curious. what this could be useful for ?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://linuxgazette.net/154/misc/lg/dns_source_port_randomisation.html

Comment: @slm: same thing i tried .. somehow didnt work :(

Comment: That was all I could find on the topic, which usually means you shouldn't be doing it that way 8-)

Answer (score 3):

The range of the [ephemeral ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) is easily tunable with 
`sysctl net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range="32768    61000"` , and you can exclude ports as well with the `net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports` parameter.

For more customization I would start by looking at the kernel source, AFAIK a start would be [net/ipv4/inet_connection_sock.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/inet_connection_sock.c#L95) where my first impression is that the assignment is random and not sequential.

```
# net/ipv4/inet_connection_sock.c
...
/* Obtain a reference to a local port for the given sock,
 * if snum is zero it means select any available local port.
 */
int inet_csk_get_port(struct sock *sk, unsigned short snum)
{
...
            inet_get_local_port_range(net, &low, &high);
            remaining = (high - low) + 1;
            smallest_rover = rover = net_random() % remaining + low;
```